# Can we get a hyperlink style for chat that is less subtle?

Tags: feature-request, design, chat

I'm open to suggestions as far as whether we should change the color, underline links, or both, but as it is it's a little too subtle for less than perfect monitors and viewing angles.

[image: chat hyperlink example]

Comment: And while we're at it lets give [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173448/can-we-get-a-paste-feature-added-to-image-uploads-in-chat) a look too ;)

Comment: I want dashed underline.

Comment: Love the answers providing users with means to implement their own solution; but I feel it is important to note (as I did on the newer duplicate) that to *my* eyes, the links are fairly distinguishable. May not be the best design implementation, but they certainly are not camouflaged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could GDSE's low-visibility hyperlinks please be revisited and improved on main, meta and in chat?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/could-gdses-low-visibility-hyperlinks-please-be-revisited-and-improved-on-main)

Comment: Voting to close this as a duplicate of the feature request where this got resolved for our record-keeping purposes.

Answer (score 8):

I've build a simple userstyle to use cause I was annoyed by it:

```
div.message a {
  color: #d1802a;
}
```

https://userstyles.org/styles/103649/make-links-identifiable

(One that also does the stars, and every other link in the star list because as far as I can tell there's no other way of telling:)

```
div.message a, #starred-posts a {
  color: #d1802a;
}
```

Comment: If you want dashed underline you can do it yourself =p

Comment: div.message div.content a {
  color: #d1802a;
  border-bottom:1px dotted;
}

Comment: +1 for a lovely work around though I still think we should push for an official solution. I honestly wasn't aware of user styles until now. Awesome!

Comment: Hm. Just noticed that this script (at least when used with GreaseMonkey, someone please confirm using Stylish) does not work on links in the stars section.

Comment: It does not, I can add a second version which does.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kevin's answer, I hacked his snippets into a userstyle that changes the colors of both the stars' links and the rest of them, and also works on all SE sites instead of just GDSE. That part can be edited in the js file.

https://userstyles.org/styles/104670/make-links-identifiable-2-0

Note: This script can be used with GreaseMonkey in FireFox or Stylish. It may work with other tools/browsers.